# Config webpack hot reload to not clear localStorage

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I'm building a Vue.js app (generated by Vue-CLI) and I'm using there a localStorage to save some data there, but on every hot-reload by webpack the localStorage becomes empty. Is there a way to config webpack to not clear it?

Comment: normally webpack can't clear your localstorage... do you call localStorage.clear() anywhere?

Comment: This shouldn't happen normally, something must be weird with your code

Comment: I'm 100% sure that I don't call `localStorage.clear()` anywhere.. But thanks for explanation, will dig deeper with my code, maybe action that removes localStorage items are called somewhere.